# Testing concurrent.futures.TimeoutError and logging in a threaded function using Pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, concurrent.futures

I've come across a testing challenge in my Python project and I'm hoping to get some insights from the community. I have a utility module containing a function `threaded_execute` which utilizes the `concurrent.futures` module to execute a function in a separate thread. If a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` occurs, it logs a warning and retries the function. I'm using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) for testing and I want to specifically test the logging of the `TimeoutError` without installing any additional packages.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import logging
from concurrent import futures

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

THREAD_TIMEOUT: float = 60  # For simplicity, just hardcoding the value here

def threaded_execute(func, *args, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    timeout = timeout or THREAD_TIMEOUT
    while True:
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            future = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
            try:
                return future.result(timeout=timeout)
            except futures.TimeoutError as exc:
                logger.warning(exc)
                continue
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html (the `caplog` fixture)?

Comment: (By the way, since there is no way to kill a thread, chances are this will deadlock if the `func` actually does hang.)

Comment: Yes, I did. But I seem to be confused with the definition of a mock function given that this is an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a mock executee that takes its sweet time on the first invocation, and none on the next:

```
import logging

import time
from concurrent import futures

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def threaded_execute(func, *args, timeout: float, **kwargs):
    while True:
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            future = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
            try:
                return future.result(timeout=timeout)
            except futures.TimeoutError as exc:
                logger.warning("Timed out", exc_info=True)
                continue


def test_threaded_execute(caplog):
    i = 0

    def fun():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        if i == 1:  # first time around, time out
            time.sleep(1)
        return f"OK {i}"

    assert threaded_execute(fun, timeout=0.5) == "OK 2"
    assert caplog.records[0].message == "Timed out"
```